# DotNetOpenAuth - OpenAuth2 in C# - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I'm rewriting some old application, written in ASP.NET MVC. It used authentication by LDAP, but now it is necessary to rewrite it to OAuth2. I've decided to use DotNetOpenAuth library as it looked like best choice, but I'm stuck on auth response.

Currently, I have one controller class called AccountController, containing some methods, but most important are RedirectToIS and PostAuth (which is an redirect uri):

```
public ActionResult RedirectToIS()
{
        DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription asd = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription();
        String site = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oauth:site"];
        asd.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(site + "/oauth/authorize");
        asd.TokenEndpoint = new Uri(site + "/oaut/token");
        asd.ProtocolVersion = DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ProtocolVersion.V20;

        this.oaclient = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient(asd, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oauth:appid"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oauth:secret"]);

        this.oaclient.RequestUserAuthorization(null, new Uri("http://localhost/Account/PostAuth"));

        return View();
}
```

The PostAuth method is what I am trying to make to work correctly. It is page, where the OAuth2 server redirect user after successful authorization with code and state GET parameters. Because I'm trying to utilize library and not (re)write it, I've stuck here - I don't know what to do now.

I tried, as I've seen in one example, use `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState st = this.oaclient.ProcessUserAuthorization();` in `PostAuth`, but it don't work. In example author had original WebServerClient instance, but I can't achieve it with Session nor using `AccountControler` data  item.

So, finally, my question: How to transfer object oaclient from RedirectToIS method to PostAuth method (some kind of session?) or how to start using OAuth?

PS: I'm not new to C#, but I've never used ASP.NET.

Comment: Just a quick question, the line new Uri(site + "/oaut/token"); Did you mean (site + "/oautH/token")?

Comment: Hi. Of course I mean. Later, I've found and repaired this and some other mistakes in code, but none led to working OAuth. So I've done the simplified version of the application in PHP, where it worked OK :))